# Compare Array Uniquely - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare, unique

I want to compare arrays by treating each index as unique

```
a1 = ['x', 'x', 'y']
a2 = ['x', 'y']

a1 compare a2 = ['x']
```

I want to compare a1 and a2 and it to return ['x']. Meaning that 'x' in a2 only removes one of the 'x' in a1.

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: Just what i describe. I want a method that compares the characters and treat then as unique.

Comment: I think he wants it to remove only the first match of 'x' in the array since 'x' only appears once in a2. Also, I'm assuming he'd want it to return 'y' as well.

a1 compare a2 = ['x', 'y']